# Surface Book 2 - CPU1 always at 89-91% usage (hot) [18.04]

Tags: cpu, overheating

I've been trying to find people with similar issues as me, and no luck. I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my newly bought Microsoft Surface Book 2 - and it's a very handy and portable machine. I know it's not "intended" to use linux on such devices, but I am a linux fan so why not.

As of a fresh install, I could notice my computer got really hot - and it stayed hot. It turns one of my CPU threads are maxed out all the time. Why is ubuntu doing this? I can't find any processes using any CPU at all when idling.

"htop" shows no significant usage on any of the processes there either, and sensor values reads around 80-98 degrees on the package constantly. So I swithced over to Windows for now.

[image: Picture shows that thread 1 is constantly on 90%]

Extra information:
[image: Extra output]

Comment: @wiking I have. I had this CPU issue with it installed, and before i installed it. I also tried putting the load of the GPU tasks solely over to the GPU and vice versa. Had no impact to my problem as i could notice

Comment: Added the extra information @Wiking

Comment: I can confirm it was kworker, however none of the available solutions worked for my part. I ended up installing 16.04 and a custom kernal with it.

Comment: I have a similar problem, any solution or workaround?

Comment: @MostafaAghajani You can try my following answer. :)

Comment: I was able to keep the Surface Book 2 heat under control on Ubuntu 20 after switching to this kernel: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface.  I had tried the jakeday kernel but it didn't seem to fix my overheating problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have the exact same issue as you. I install Arch Linux on my Surface Book 2, and `kworker/acpi_notify` always eat a CPU core.

In your `ps -eo pid,comm,%cpu` output, kworker also consumes high CPU.

**Workaround**:

add `acpi=off` to the kernel parameters. But this may be not acceptable since all acpi functionalities are lost.

**Solution**:

The issue is the ACPI notify module, use this patched kernel to fix the issue:

> https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/

For Ubuntu, you can just use the pre-built kernel directly.

If you want to compile from source on a non-ubuntu system, try [this guide](https://github.com/atupal/snippet/blob/master/arch_and_linux/kernel/surface_book2_acpi_high_cpu.md#so-the-finaly-solution-is-use-this-surface-kernel-httpsgithubcomjakedaylinux-surface) or the above Github repo.